EXCEL IF AND Formula in excel to not calculate any date 31/12
=IF(AND(AND(DAY(G6)<>31,MONTH(G6)<>12),OR(I6="AT",I6="CH",I6="DE",I6="NL",I6="SE")),"Keep","Delete Line")
G6 has a date in DD/MM/YYYY (If 31/12 it must calculate to Delete Line)
I6 has a Country Code in fyi
I am finding the above formula is finding 31/05/2024 in column G and calculating "Delete Line" instead of "Keep"?  I only want to Delete Line if 31/12.
Any ideas please experts
Thanks in advance

Are you sure about the "DD/MM", it's not "MM/DD"?

I will look into your suggestion thanks but as UK we use DD/MM.

I think this should be your formula:
=IF(AND(OR(DAY(G6)<>31;MONTH(G6)<>12);OR(I6="AT";I6="CH";I6="DE";I6="NL";I6="SE"));"Keep";"Delete Line")
        ^^
        ^^ (OR instead of AND)

You have forgotten that: NOT(A AND B) = (NOT (A)) OR (NOT (B)).

Thank you for looking into this for me but I am afraid your suggestion doesnt work.

Go to Formula auditing, you can evaluate your formula step by step, and like this you can see what's going wrong (this is the way I found this issue).

Thank you Dominique, I appreciate your suggestion
